# Google places API - Can I separate out the output?

Tags: google-places-api

Hiting the endpoint:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Hoboken%20NJ&fields=formatted_address,name&inputtype=textquery&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Getting the result:

```
{
   "candidates" : [
      {
         "formatted_address" : "New Jersey, USA",
         "name" : "Hoboken"
      }
   ],
   "debug_log" : {
      "line" : []
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

What bugs me is that I can't find a way to separate out the region and country - **Yes, I know I can parse the result myself**. But is there an option I get shoot out to Google Places API to have the response separate out city/state(or region)/country in the returned JSON?

Something like:

```
{
   "candidates" : [
      {
         "state" : "New Jersey",
         "country" : "USA",
         "name" : "Hoboken"
      }
   ],
   "debug_log" : {
      "line" : []
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it isn't possible, you'll have to parse it. Places API is designed to search businesses and POIs at first place.

Google does have, however a [geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1) which seems to give out Postal Code, Country, State, Address, separetely.

There are also [some](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) free alternatives

Comment: Thanks. That API is actually what I needed.